# What's the right way to initialize resources in a multi-threaded program in Clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure, apache-storm

I am aware of components and system(haven't used them though), but I would like to know how to initialize a resource, when the init method can run from any thread. Let's say we have 10 threads, and they all use the db, and the threads can start in any order. How do I initialize the db connection pool in such a case?

I currently use compare and set to do this, but somehow it doesn't feel right.
This is what I do.

```
(let [datasource (atom nil)]
  (defn pooled-conn
    "Get a Hikari pooled connection to the database. There will only be one
  connection pool for the vm. Additional calls to this function will return
  the same connection pool. The connection pool will be created by the first
  call to this function"
    [datasource-options]
    (when (nil? @datasource)
      (let [ds (make-datasource datasource-options)]
        (when-not (compare-and-set! datasource nil {:datasource ds})
          (close-datasource ds))))
    @datasource))
```

I don't know when the vm starts, just when my thread starts(I am using storm, db pool is initialized in some bolts). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You mentioned components and system, you could also check out [mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount) for a more natural clojure feel.

Comment: Looks cool @Shlomi, will check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `locking` function.  It is like `synchronized` in Java.

Please see the full docs here:  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/locking

You're code will then resemble:

```
(def datasource (atom))
(locking datasource
  (when (nil? @datasource))
    (reset! datasource (make-datasource datasource-options))))
```

Note that you don't really need the map inside the atom.

Comment: Looks much better. Thank you!